# Trying to bake diffuse map without lighting influence (direct or indirect), but there still seems to be some influence. How to prevent it?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

I'm trying to bake the color of this object (a boot) to a new image texture:

[image]

I want the resulting image texture to be flat, without any influence from lights. So I set the bake like this, with only "color" enabled (no "direct" and no "indirect"):

[image]

However, when I bake, it still seems to have some kind of influence from lighting.
As you can see in the baked result, the buckles of the boot seem to have inprinted on the texture of the boot object underneath:

[image]

I don't understand why. Is it a bug? How can I prevent that? Or is there another way to bake a "pure" color texture?

EDIT:
Someone asked to see the material. Here it is... The Base Color texture is a simple tileable leather texture, so the inprints of the buckles are not in the original texture. But they appear in the diffuse bake even if "direct" and "indirect" are turned off. (also I'm not using any ambient occlusion nodes or nothing of the sort, only an 'RGB Curves' to adjust the color of the leather.

[image]

Comment: Show us the material(s).

Comment: I think Nathan was just checking if you had Ambient Occlusion nodes or something similar. @AlexandreMarcati

Comment: Ok, I see now how that could be relevant. However that's not the case of my situation. I don't understand what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a Principled shader, with a non-zero specular.  That means that your material output isn't 100% diffuse; some of it is diffuse mixed with specular.  How much of it is specular?  Depends on the internal Fresnel calculations of the Principled, and depends on how baking handles view dependent effects like Fresnel.  I believe this is responsible for what you're seeing (but I can't be sure without testing it out on the file.)  Your normal maps may impact whatever calculations Blender is making to determine the mix.

Where the baking algorithm decides that it should be using more specular-- and hence less diffuse-- the diffuse color is darker.

What I would recommend doing is plugging your RGB curve output directly into your material output and then baking emission.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test your suggestion and also test turning specular to zero and see what happens.

Comment: A side question: is there a way to bake a "pure" color map that doesn't take into account the specular, metallic, etcetera? In other words, something that just bakes the Base Color input into a new image?

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati Yeah, plug the color into output and bake emission.

Comment: Sure! But that seems like a 'hack' (even though the result is correct). I mean, it would be nice to have an option to bake 'base color' in the bake settings or something like that.

Comment: So, turning down specular to zero did not work. However, the suggested workaround of plugging the color to the output and baking the emission worked perfectly. I'm marking your answer as the solution. Thank you.

Comment: In my case it was the Sheen not Specular, but thanks this answer got me in the right place.